# 2D inverse Fourier transform of $\frac{\mathrm{exp}(-|\mathbf{k}|^{2})}{1+|\mathbf{k}|^{2}}$

Tags: fourier-transform, bessel-functions, error-function

I enconter a problem in 2D fluid mechanics, where I need the 2D inverse Fourier transform of the following function:
$$\frac{\mathrm{exp}(-|\mathbf{k}|^{2})}{1+|\mathbf{k}|^{2}},$$
where $\mathbf{k}=(k_{x}, k_{y})$, $|\mathbf{k}|^{2}=k_{x}^{2}+k_{y}^{2}$. The inverse Fourier transform of a function is defined as:
$$
F(x, y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f\left(k_x, k_y\right) 
e^{-i\left(k_x x+k_y y\right)} d k_x d k_y.
$$
I searched around it seems related to the Bessel function and error function but as it is 2D, I am really not familiar with it, can anyone help?

Comment: Well, $$\begin{align}
\mathscr{F^{-1}}\{f\}(x,y)&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(k_x,k_y)e^{-i(k_xx+k_yy)}\,dk_x\,dk_y\\\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-k^2}}{1+k^2}e^{-ik\rho\cos(\phi)}\,k\,dk\,d\phi\\\\
&=2\pi \int_0^\infty \frac{ke^{-k^2}}{1+k^2}J_0(k\rho)\,dk
\end{align}$$I don't know if there is a closed-form solution.

Comment: thank you for the answer, so it looks like a Hankel transform $H_{0}(\rho)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-k^2}}{1+k^2}kJ_{0}(k\rho)dk$?

Comment: Yes indeed.  It is a Hankel transform.   The integrand is rapidly decaying and so numerical integration should be a snap.